# How to Compare Multiple Columns, and Produce Values in single New Column , Using Apply Function in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-apply

Using the Apply Function in Pandas, I want to compare Multiple Columns in a Datafarme , to see if there values are Higher or Lower than a Numerical Value. Than Based on the Result of the Condition If Higher or Lower, i will output a String Value in a New Column. I'am able to do this when comparing 1 Column to the Numerical Value, but not with Multiple Columns. How would i do this with Multiple Columns ? Below is Example i'm using. The example works well for 1 Column , but i cannot get it done for multiple columns. In addition to "Column C" which im comparing to the numerical Value "99". I want to also compare "Columns B" and "Columns D" to the numerical Value "99".

(Note: I do not want to use Lambda function method)

Code is below,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

```
data = { 'a': [1, 15, 27, 399], 
         'b': [2, 30, 45, 60],
         'c': [100,200, 3, 78],
         'd': [4, 300, 400, 500]
         }

dfgrass = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
def judge(x):
    if x > 99:
        return 'bingo'
    elif x < 99:
        return 'jack'

dfgrass['e'] = dfgrass['c'].apply(judge)

print(dfgrass)
```

Comment: Just for Columns A, B, C . Im sorry i was suppose to replace A with D instead. So its for Columns B,C, D. I will edit that now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['e'] = np.where(df[['a','b','c']].gt(99).any(axis=1), 'jack', 'bingo')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     a   b    c    d      e
0    1   2  100    4  bingo
1   15  30  200  300  bingo
2   27  45    3  400   jack
3  399  60   78  500   jack
```

Answer (score 0):

To use your function with multiple columns you need 2 things:

1. Use `axis=1` as parameter of `apply` to pass each rows to your function else your function receive columns.
2. Inside your function if you use conditional statements you have to use `any` or `all` (or anything else like `sum`) to aggregate / reduce the boolean vectors else your function will raise the well known `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

You can modify your function as below:

```
def judge(x):
    if any(x > 99):  # <- HERE
        return 'bingo'
    else:
        return 'jack'

dfgrass['e'] = dfgrass[['b', 'c', 'd']].apply(judge, axis=1)  # <- HERE
print(df)

# Output:
     a   b    c    d      e
0    1   2  100    4  bingo
1   15  30  200  300  bingo
2   27  45    3  400  bingo
3  399  60   78  500  bingo
```